# Change binary subtype in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, binary, subtype

Is it possible to change only the subtype of the Binary element in MongoDB?
I have Binary element in database of type 0x00
`BinData(0, xxx)`
Is it possible via shell to update only the subType part of this element/change it to another value?

Or the only way is to create new property with old binary part?

```
new BinData(newVal, xxx)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the only way is to create new [`BinData`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#binary) using the previous `base64` value. Of course to get that value you only need to call the `.base64()` method.

```
> var bin = new BinData(3,"ASNFZ4mrze/+3LqYdlQyEA==")
> var newType = 0;
> bin = new BinData(newType, bin.base64());
BinData(0,"ASNFZ4mrze/+3LqYdlQyEA==")
```

The reason is that the `type` property is not *writable* as shown by the output of [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(bin, 'type')
{
        "configurable" : true,
        "enumerable" : false,
        "value" : 0,
        "writable" : false
}
```

For example:

```
> bin.type;
0
> bin.type = 3;
3
> bin.type;
0
```

You can see that value of `bin.type` remains unchanged even after *setting* it to `3`